# How to call these methods with a trigger?

Tags: apex, callout

I am currently calling this class with a Process Builder. But I can't see the results of the code following the @Future statement. I've looked through debug logs as well as in the Apex Jobs list and cannot find them. Am I unable to see them run because they are following a @Future statement ? Or is it because it's a second method in a class being called by a Process Builder ? Or is there another way I need to try and see it run ?

Should I be calling the methods individually from a trigger ?

```
public class UpdateContactPCRController_SELECTED {


    @InvocableMethod
    public static List<String> updateContact(List<String> recordId){ 
        
        //Variable to hold the contact Id
        String contactId = '';
        
        //List ot update contact
        List<Contact> contactToBeupdate = new List<Contact>();
        

        if(recordId.size()> 0){  
            
            //Get Program Contact Role
            //List<Program_Contact_Role__c> programContacList = [SELECT Id,Contact__c,Program_Name__c FROM Program_Contact_Role__c WHERE Id =:recordId AND Contact__c != null];
            //SELECTED
            List<Program_Contact_Role__c> programContacList = [SELECT Id,Contact__c,Program_Name__c FROM Program_Contact_Role__c WHERE Id =:recordId[0] AND Contact__c != null];
            System.debug(recordId[0]);
    
            //if(programContacList.size() > 0)
                contactId = programContacList[0].Contact__c;
                
            
            if(String.isNotBlank(contactId)){
                
                contactToBeupdate = [Select Id,Pardot_Action_Trigger__c,PCR_Register_Button_Link__c,PCR_URL_for_UI__c FROM Contact Where Id =: contactId Limit 1];
                
                contactToBeupdate[0].Pardot_Action_Trigger__c = 'Send Welcome Email';                contactToBeupdate[0].Program_Contact_Role_Id__c = recordId[0];
            }
            
  

            List<Program_Communication_Recipients__c> programCommunicationRecs = [Select Id,Name,Program_Communication__r.Welcome_Message__c,
                                                                                         Program_Communication__r.Program__r.Buyer__r.Name,Receipient__c,
                                                                                         Program_Communication__r.Program__r.Buyer__r.Account_Name_for_Communications__c,
                                                                                         Program_Communication__r.Logo_Public_Url__c ,Welcome_Page_with_IDs__c, 
                                                                                         Program_Communication__r.URL_for_UI__c ,Program_Communication__r.Learn_More_link__c,
                                                                                         Program_Communication__r.Reply_to_Email__c,Program_Communication__r.From_Email__c                
                                                                                         From Program_Communication_Recipients__c Where 
                                                                                         Program_Communication__r.Program__c =: programContacList[0].Program_Name__c AND 
                                                                                         Receipient__c =: programContacList[0].Id];
                                                   
            
            if(programCommunicationRecs.size() > 0){
                
                if(String.isNotBlank(programCommunicationRecs[0].Welcome_Page_with_IDs__c))
                    contactToBeupdate[0].PCR_Register_Button_Link__c = programCommunicationRecs[0].Welcome_Page_with_IDs__c;
                
                
                
                if(String.isNotBlank(programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Learn_More_link__c))
                            contactToBeupdate[0].PCR_Learn_More_Link__c = programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Learn_More_link__c;
                        
                if(String.isNotBlank(programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.URL_for_UI__c))
                    contactToBeupdate[0].PCR_URL_for_UI__c = programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.URL_for_UI__c;
                    

               
               if(String.isNotBlank(programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Program__r.Buyer__r.Account_Name_for_Communications__c))
                    contactToBeupdate[0].PCR_Buyer_Name__c = programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Program__r.Buyer__r.Account_Name_for_Communications__c;
               if(String.isBlank(programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Program__r.Buyer__r.Account_Name_for_Communications__c))
                    contactToBeupdate[0].PCR_Buyer_Name__c = programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Program__r.Buyer__r.Name;
               //END CHANGE
                
                if(String.isNotBlank(programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Welcome_Message__c) && String.valueOf(programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Welcome_Message__c).length()> 254)
                    contactToBeupdate[0].PCR_Welcome_Message__c = String.valueOf(programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Welcome_Message__c).substring(0, 254);
                else 
                    contactToBeupdate[0].PCR_Welcome_Message__c = String.valueOf(programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Welcome_Message__c);
                
                contactToBeupdate[0].PCR_Buyer_Logo_Url__c = programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Logo_Public_Url__c;
                
                 
                contactToBeupdate[0].From_Email__c = programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.From_Email__c;
                contactToBeupdate[0].Reply_to_Email__c = programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Reply_to_Email__c;
            }
        }

        
        System.debug('TESTER DEBUGGER1');
        if(contactToBeupdate.size() > 0){
            update contactToBeupdate;  
        }
        

        List<String> response = new List<String>();
        System.debug('TESTER DEBUGGER2');
        response.add('Updated Successfully');
        System.debug('TESTER DEBUGGER-PRE-FUTURE');
        return response;
        
    }
   
    @future(callout=true) 
    public static void pardotCallout(String contactId) {
        String returnedResponseFromPardot = Http_Utility_Pardot.pardotCreateProspect(new Set<Id> {contactId});
        System.debug('TESTER DEBUGGER-POST-FUTURE');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you "call" a future method, it's queued for later execution in a separate transaction. You'll need to check your debug logs to find a separate transaction. See this example:

[image: Example Debug Logs]

The FutureHandler entry is where the future method is actually executed. You'll want to open the [Developer Console](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console.htm&type=5) to see this separate log easily.

Comment: I have been looking in the Debug Logs, but don't see it. I guess it would have to be a different type of user to track in order to see the log for that particular action ? Or shouldn't it also appear in the Apex Jobs ? Is this Logs in the Developer Console showing different than in the Debug Logs ? Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to use the Debug Logs still, but I still don't see a FutureHandler operation appearing in it. The rest of the class is running ok. Is there something else I need to be doing ? Do I need to track a different type of user in order to see that type of code run ? I don't see it in Apex Jobs either. I don't see anything in the code which would prevent it from advancing to the Future portion of the code. Thank you.

Comment: ok - I'm now seeing FutureHandler operations for other classes which contain Future methods in my Debug Log as well as my Apex Jobs. So I know it's not a matter of not properly viewing the logs. They are from classes which are initiated through updates to records from this class. But for some reason I can't see this last Future method on this class. I don't get it. It's like it's not running. Do you see anything in that class which would prevent it from running that last method with the Future ?

Comment: An exception being thrown somewhere in the original transaction would explain it.